# Intellij IDEA: Why build.sbt is highlighted in red?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

After a 2 year pause I resumed work with PlayFramework. So I created a new Play Scala project via Intellij IDEA. But the result was strange:

1. Content of `build.sbt` is highlighted in red
2. The project contains `build.gradle` O_o

So the question is: why content of the `build.sbt` is underlined in red?[image]

Comment: Do you have the scala / sbt plugins installed?

Comment: @tgk yes. Scala plugin Version: 2017.3.11

Comment: Check if you don't have `build.sbt` displayed twice - once within your project directory and another one within root (it sound weird I know) - in my case I see content of my build's root twice, and one list is treated as part of my project (so e.g. syntax highlithing works), while the other one is not. If you opened build.sbt "wrongly" you might get red hightlights. I think it is a bug in IntelliJ.

Comment: To clarify what I mean -> https://i.imgur.com/T1vGfr7.png <- files in root of the Scala project are displayed twice, if you open them by clicking on file with red background, it will not be treated as part of the project, so no syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: Other possibility might be that you haven't refreshed SBT after adding dependencies: View > Tool windows > SBT and then refresh button.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I have only one `build.sbt` file in project, so the case #1 is not applicable. Unfortunately suggestion #2 does not help s well :(

Comment: I have also upgraded to IntelliJ 2017.3 Community Edition all my existing Play projects cannot be normally imported now. This is really a PITA.

Comment: same thing happens to me going from 2017.x to 2018.1 did you manage to fix this @AlexFruzenshtein ?

Comment: @Havnar I left the idea to work with Paly Framework :D

Answer (score 5):

That's a known issue which will be fixed shortly. As a work-around, please close the project and re-import it.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13283

Comment: unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `build.sbt` (actually any files named `*.sbt`) are in the project’s base directory. I unknowingly moved mine to the target directory once. It was very hard to see given that `build.sbt` is normally displayed right below the target directory. Everything goes red, but everything still works like it did when `build.sbt` started where it was supposed to be.